# how to create new horizontal row for each field in django form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Very new to django. I would like to have each field in a modelform in a new row on the html page. I've tried to use  but that doesn't work. How can I do this? Here is the html I have for the page that displays my form for capturing data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <thead><th>{{title}}</th>   

        {% for record in record_list%}
        <tr><td>{{record.county}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.route}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.pmb}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.pme}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.map_sheet_desc}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.drawingdate}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.index_map_filepath}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.grantor_box_filepath}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.control_map_filepath}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.info_sheet_filepath}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{record.mapdatum}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <form method="POST" action="/update/">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create Map Index Record</legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form_mapindex}}
            <br><button type="submit">Create Record</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code in my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Mapindex as MapIndexModel
from .forms import MapIndexForm

class MapIndexView(View):
    template_name = 'add.html'

    def get(self, request):
        record_list = []
        form_mapindex = MapIndexForm()
        records = MapIndexModel.objects.all()[:50]

        for record in records:
            record_list.append({'county': record.county, 'route': record.route, 'pmb': record.pmb, 'pme': record.pme,
                                'map_sheet_desc': record.map_sheet_desc, 'drawingdate': record.drawingdate,
                                'index_map_filepath': record.index_map_filepath, 'grantor_box_filepath': record.grantor_box_filepath,
                                'control_map_filepath': record.control_map_filepath, 'info_sheet_filepath': record.info_sheet_filepath,
                                'mapdatum': record.mapdatum})

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'title': 'Map Index Update Form',
            'mapindex_list': record_list,
            'form_mapindex': form_mapindex
        })

    def post(self, request):
        form_mapindex = MapIndexForm(request.POST)
        if form_mapindex.is_valid():
            form_mapindex.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/update/')
```

and here is forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Mapindex

class MapIndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mapindex
        fields = ['county', 'route', 'pmb', 'pme', 'map_sheet_desc', 'drawingdate', 'index_map_filepath',
                  'grantor_box_filepath', 'control_map_filepath', 'info_sheet_filepath', 'mapdatum']
```

Comment: Your post is missing some information. What is it that you tried to use? What's in the view for this template?

Comment: thanks for the relply, I wasn't sure what else I should include in the post, but just updated to show my views.py as well.

Comment: I think a difference between the example I am using and what I am after is I don't care to see the existing records, I just want to add new records. Will keep looking at it

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `record_list` but assigning it to `mapindex_list`. Either iterate through `mapindex_list` in the template or change the name in the render function to match:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'title': 'Map Index Update Form',
            'record_list': record_list,
            'form_mapindex': form_mapindex
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for noticing that, i'm still figuring out what things mean. I notice when I change it to record_list as you have above, the template now shows records in the existing table, instead of a form to add new records. What am I missing? I adapted the code from this site: https://codingair.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/django-use-modelform-to-list-and-create-user-data/

Comment: It ought to be showing both: the form under the rows. If it's not, look closely at `form_mapindex`

Comment: I posted my forms.py as well where I create the form class. still not sure what is happening.

Comment: Trying printing out the form in the view to the console; it should be a form instance. View source on the rendered HTML page; where does it stop displaying? Might also be a good to simplify—try making a view/template with _just_ the form, or learn how to do Django unit testing—it'll pay in the long term!

Comment: yes I just started to simplify and am testing, thanks for your helpful tips!